# I'm trying to get the radio button's text(from a fragment) but it's showing null pointer exception

Tags: android, radio-button, fragment

Actually I am a beginner to android , I want to show the selected `radio button's` text as a toast but I'm unable to get the text and it's showing null point exception error.

My Code is:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
 show = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.show);
 gender = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.gender);
 show.setOnClickListener(this);
 return v;}
  public void onClick(View view) {
  int id=gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(id);
    String user_gender=radio.getText().toString();
    switch (view.getId()){
     case R.id.show:
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),user_gender,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       break;}}
```

My error in logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: community.infinity, PID: 24245
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                    at layout.fragment.onClick(fragment.java:118)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can give it a try.**

```
 //Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in current group.
 int id = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

 if(id !=-1){
     //get radio button view
        View radioButton = rg1.findViewById(id);
     // return index of selected radiobutton
        int radioId = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
     // based on index getObject of radioButton
        RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg1.getChildAt(radioId);
     //After getting radiobutton you can now use all its methods
        String selection = (String) btn.getText();
    }
```

Comment: thanks sir it worked perfectly but can you explain it

Comment: Thanks sir for explanation

Answer (score 0):

**change this in your code** 
`RadioButton radio=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(id);`

**to this** 
`RadioButton radio=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(id);`

**like this**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
 show = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.show);
 gender = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.gender);
    public void onClick(View view) {
  int id=gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    RadioButton radio=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(id);

    String user_gender=radio.getText().toString();
    switch (view.getId()){
     case R.id.show:
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),user_gender,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       break;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code;

```
  radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

});
```